# SQL Server 2008 write TSQL to run in earlier versions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

In Visual Studio 2010, while creating new projects, we may select target version to .Net Framework 2.0, .Net Framework 3.0 etc. Is there anything available in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio with the same functionality, that is the created T SQL command should run in SQL Server 2000,SQL Server 2005 etc.

For example, in SQL Server 2008, I created a procedure which uses `data` data type.I got error when I tried to run it in SQL Server 2005. So I changed the data type to `datetime`

Comment: Nowadays there's no excuse for not running a real copy of SQL Server 2005.  You can run it on a a virtual machine, on a server, on a server in a virtual machine.  The free 2005 express edition is still available for download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with SQL Server 2012 Data Tools - you can target 2005, 2008, 2012, even Azure, and it will warn you when you are using syntax that is invalid for your target version. It won't re-write it for you, though - it just uses the specified version of the SQL parser to validate the code you wrote.

SSDT is free:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg427686

I don't think there is any way to simulate this functionality in Management Studio unless you actually execute against a 2005 instance - in which case, again, it will tell you where you've gone wrong, but it won't fix your code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a "target", but there is the DB compatibility level which you can set on the DB. While this does not completely hide all features of the new versions, it will make the DB behave "like" the old version for most purposes.

Comment: It's in the properties of the database (not the server/instance).

Comment: This doesn't help for the particular issue the OP cites: you can still use the new data types. It's largely for TSQL parsing conventions and some functions' behaviour.

Comment: @ta.speot.is, that's the reason why I explicitly wrote that it doesn't hide all new features.

Comment: @Lucero Yes. It does not give what I really needed. Any alternatives ?